# Links with plain URLs as markdown code don't automatically display the title of the question when one link in the post doesn't have a plain URL code

Tags: bug, questions, markdown, hyperlinks, title

I recently edited [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/295583/4284627) to change the text displayed on one of the links. The question is asking why burnination request questions often have funny titles and had a list of links to examples of questions with these kinds of titles, all links in that list used plain URL as markdown code, which automatically displayed the titles of the questions. Since one of those questions had changed title, I decided to edit it so that the link would display the old title instead, which is more relevant to the question.

This is the code of how the link was displayed first:

```
http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295233/should-we-throw-corners-in-the-corner
```

I edited it into the following:

```
[Should we throw the [corners] in the corner?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295233/should-we-throw-corners-in-the-corner)
```

I only edited that link and left all the other links alone, since their titles were still relevant to the question. The problem is that doing so messed up the formatting of all the other links:

[image]

As you can see, the link to which I gave a custom text was displayed fine, but all the other links lost their automatic formatting and displayed the URLs instead of the titles.

When I noticed that, I undid my edit. That didn't solve the problem, the links were still displayed as URLs. So I tried to rollback, and that didn't either solve the problem. So the only way I could solve this problem was to manually edit each link to make it display the title of the question.

Could this bug please be fixed?

Comment: Maybe it has to do with the switch to HTTPS? Otherwise, I can't think of anything obvious for why this just stopped working.